# Numpy and linear algebra: How to code Axꞏy?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I've some difficulty in matching what Numpy expects when performing the dot product and vector representation in linear algebra, in term of shapes.

Let's say I've a matrix and two column vectors represented by Numpy arrays:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1,2],
              [3,1],
              [-5,2]])

x = np.array([[0],
              [2]])

y = np.array([[-2],
              [0],
              [3]])
```

and I want to compute `Axꞏy`, `Ax` being a matrix multiplication and `ꞏ` being the dot product. This doesn't work:

```
# a = Axꞏy
a = (A @ x).dot(y)
```

> shapes (3,1) and (3,1) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

`Ax`:

```
[[4],
 [2],
 [4]]
```

is indeed a column vector and the dot product of the two column vectors is the scalar: `-8+0+12=4`, this is the result I'm expecting.

What is the correct operation or reshaping required, using vectors as they are defined?

Comment: `A@x` has shape `(3, 1)`, which is not compatible for a dot product with a `(3, 1)` array, did you mean `(A@x).T @ y` (or `(A@x) @ y.T`)? What is the expected output?

Comment: sum( y * ( A @ x ) )[0]

Comment: @mins please provide the exact expected output for clarity.

Comment: Can you break down how you get `12` from `array([[4],[2],[4]])` and `array([[-2],[0],[3]])`?

Comment: OK, then `((A@x).T @ y).item()`

Comment: Review how `np.dot` and `np.matmul` handle arrays with different shapes.

Comment: @mins yes, a dot product of 2D arrays requires shapes to be `(n, k)` and `(k, m)`

Comment: The 'dot' you expect is also called the 'scalar product'.  `np.dot` does do that for 1d arrays.  But in numpy a (3,1) shape is 2d (a 1 column matrix).  So you have to adjust terminology a bit.

Comment: Technically numpy doesn't have 'vectors',  Shapes (3,), (3,1), (1,3) all can function as such, but none exactly fits the common linear algebra definitions.

Comment: Using `ravel()` to turn a (n,1) array to (n,), `A@x.ravel()@y.ravel()` is a simple solution.  It's a (3,2) with a (2,) with a (3,), resulting in a scalar `4`.

Comment: `np.einsum('ij,jk,ik->', A, x, y)`

Comment: You will have a very difficult time if you continue to use numpy with a concept of columns as 2d arrays and row vectors as 1d arrays.

Comment: A vector is a 1 dimensional Array and not a 2 dimensional Array. if you have `x = np.array([0,2])` and `y=  np.array([-2,0,3])` then your code should work. ie `A@x@y`. The issue is you are having a 2 dimensional array and claim its a vector. No thats a matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't compute a dot product between two `(3, 1)` arrays, a dot product `A @ B` is only valid if the shape of `A` and `B` are `(n, k)` and `(k, m)`.

It looks like you want:

```
(A@x).T @ y
```

Output: `[[4]]`

Or as scalar:

```
((A@x).T @ y).item()
```

Output: `4`

*NB. in the context of 2D arrays `@` and `dot` are equivalent.*

---

Other operations that would have been valid given the shapes:

```
(A@x) @ y.T

array([[-8,  0, 12],
       [-4,  0,  6],
       [-8,  0, 12]])


(A.T*x) @ y

array([[0],
       [4]])
```